# XY coords following cursor movements

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, coordinates, mouse, onmouseover

i am looking to have this cursor effect on the body:

https://www.screenshot-magazine.com/

i do have two separate codes, one for the bloc following the mouse and another to get the xy coords.
But i am too beginner to merge both together or make both work in parallel to have the XY coods printed in the box following my cursor moves.

Someone could help me?
Thanks a lot in advance:)
Anto

here the two codes:

1-bloc following mouse movements

```
<style>
#divtoshow {
position:absolute;
display:none;
color: #C0C0C0;
background-color: none;
}

<script type="text/javascript">
var divName = 'divtoshow'; // div that is to follow the mouse (must be position:absolute)
var offX = 15;          // X offset from mouse position
var offY = 15;          // Y offset from mouse position

function mouseX(evt) {if (!evt) evt = window.event; if (evt.pageX) return evt.pageX; else if (evt.clientX)return evt.clientX + (document.documentElement.scrollLeft ?  document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft); else return 0;}
function mouseY(evt) {if (!evt) evt = window.event; if (evt.pageY) return evt.pageY; else if (evt.clientY)return evt.clientY + (document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop); else return 0;}

function follow(evt) {
var obj = document.getElementById(divName).style;
obj.left = (parseInt(mouseX(evt))+offX) + 'px';
obj.top = (parseInt(mouseY(evt))+offY) + 'px'; 
}

document.onmousemove = follow;
</script>

<body>
<div id='onme' onMouseover='document.getElementById(divName).style.display="block"' onMouseout='document.getElementById(divName).style.display="none"'>
<div id="divtoshow">test</div>
```

2-get XY coords on body

```
<script>
function readMouseMove(e){
var result_x = document.getElementById('x_result');
var result_y = document.getElementById('y_result');
result_x.innerHTML = e.clientX;
result_y.innerHTML = e.clientY;
}
document.onmousemove = readMouseMove;
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2 id="x_result">0</h2>
<h2 id="y_result">0</h3>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is fine. You could have moved `#x-result` and `#y-result` into `#divtoshow`, and then set the `left` and `right` in `readMouseMove`. I've modified your code a bit. I'll explain it on the way

```js
const xResult = document.getElementById("x-result");
const yResult = document.getElementById("y-result");
const divToShow = document.getElementById("divtoshow");

document.onmousemove = function (e) {
  let mouse = {
    x: e.clientX, // this is 2018, so you can just directly use clientX
    y: e.clientY // and clientY
  };

  divToShow.style.left = `${mouse.x + 16}px`; // add a padding so that the text is not rendered directly below the mouse
  divToShow.style.top = `${mouse.y + 16}px`;

  xResult.innerHTML = `X: ${mouse.x}`; // write the text into the output divs
  yResult.innerHTML = `Y: ${mouse.y}`;
};
```

```css
#divtoshow {
  color: #C0C0C0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="divtoshow">
  <span id="x-result">X: 0</span> <br> // i changed the h2s to spans because h2s have HUGE text
  <span id="y-result">Y: 0</span>
</div>
```

You can add the `#onme` integration by yourself.

Comment: Hello Kartha! thank you so much this is just great, i got it in theory, coz i don't know why but it doesn't work out here with me...strange

Comment: i am adding your code in a <script> in the head but doesn't get the xy coords value live...i have the x:0 y:0 following well the cursor but not getting coords, am i missing something to complete change in your lines? thanks in advance